# Remove current time stamp from FileName using FileSaver.js in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

I am using fileSaver to download a `CSV` file in JavaScript. While downloading the file the current time will get append at the last of downloaded fileName.

Expected file name: `xyz-29092918-28092019.csv`
Actual file name: `xyz-29092918-28092019-2019-09-20T001653.611.csv`

Here is the code am using to download a file using fileSaver

```
let blob = new Blob([response], {
    type: "multipart/form-data"
});

saveAs(blob, "xyz-29092918-28092019.csv")
```

Comment: This does not reproduce the problem, and the library itself does not have any logic to introduce this behavior. It seems like your browser is adding the timestamp, so including the OS and browser you're testing on would be relevant here to provide a [mcve].

Comment: If this is browser or OS issue then it should append the current time stamp in other file as well. I mean to say it should be same for all the file am downloading but it's not showing for all. Some files are downloading as expected.

Comment: A common reason for appending a time stamp like this is when the OS detects that your selected download folder contains a filename that matches the filename of the download.

Comment: Thanks Patrick I checked to download file on IE its showing correct name of file.